# CNN training with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Good day I'm currently trying to run a CNN model on my VS code, all the cells are running perfectly aside from the cell that is for loading the architectures and training the model.

```
import sys

# loop through each model
for base_model, model_name, preprocessing in zip(base_models,
                                                 model_names,
                                                 preprocess_inputs):

  # setup model architecture
  try:
    base_model = base_model(input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE,
                            include_top=False,
                            weights='imagenet')
  except:
     print(f"{model_name} training failed:")
     print(sys.exc_info()[0])
     continue

  model = build_model(base_model, preprocessing)

  # which model is currently training?
  print("*" * 50)
  print(f"{model_name} model training...")

  # compile the model
  base_learning_rate = 0.0001
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

  # callbacks
  run_logdir = get_run_logdir(model_name)
  tensorboard_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(run_logdir)

  # train the model
  initial_epochs = 10
  model.fit(train_ds, epochs=initial_epochs,
            validation_data=val_ds,
            callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])

  # evaluate the model on test set
  print("*" * 50)
  print(f"{model_name} test set evaluation:")
  model.evaluate(test_ds)

  # save the model after training
  model_fn = os.path.join(work_dir, "models", f"{model_name}_{crop}_base.h5")
  model.save(model_fn)
```

The error that i got is "Cannot execute code, session has been disposed. Please try restarting the Kernel. The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details." I have tried to use different python version as well as different tensorflow versions, i also clear the cache on the command prompt, the training process is actually working on google colab but i always run though run time error so i tried to train on my local machine

meanwhile the error that i got on my jupyter is

```
Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221226505, Reason: 2023-06-27 18:52:57.666162: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

Comment: Could you please add the code and error message?

Comment: Good day I have added the code and additional error message from jupyter

Comment: Please dont link pictures of the code and error. Paste it in the text. This seems a good explanation why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: my apologies, I have updated the post and I hope that you can help me

Comment: Are you sure your tensorflow installation is appropriate to your machine? Not the version, the pre-compiled backend. (i.e. CUDA, CPU-only, etc) The error message shows that the backend is "oneDNN". Was that intended?